# Using jq to read in json as an array

Tags: bash, zsh, jq

I have this example `test.json` file:

```
{
    "folder": {
    "name": "Desktop",
    "path": "Users/user/Desktop",
    "executable": false
    }
}
```

I am trying to read the object contained in 'folder' into a variable `$var` as an array. Desired output - `$var` contains the following:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Desktop",
    "path": "Users/user/Desktop",
    "executable": false
  }
]
```

It seemed relatively straightforward. `jq '.folder' test.json` to read in the folder value, and then pipe the output using the `-s` flag to get it enclosed in an array. This command executes just fine:

```
jq '.folder' test.json | jq -s
```

However, when I try to save the result to a variable, it throws an error displaying the `jq` usage statement. What am I missing? Is there a different way to accomplish this?

```
var=$(jq '.folder' test.json | jq -s)
echo $var
```

I also found out that this works fine in `zsh` but throws an error in `bash`. Not sure if that's relevant and whether it has to do with different versions of `jq`

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: I did - it's the second code block

Comment: The problem you encountered piping into `jq -s` has been resolved but when in doubt, simply provide an explicit argument, e.g. `jq -s .`.  In the present case, though, the best solution is to invoke jq just once.  Please note that with jq 1.5 and up, the -s option is often best avoided for efficiency reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you were expecting ?

```
$ var="$(jq "[.folder]" test.json)"
$ echo "$var"
[
  {
    "name": "Desktop",
    "path": "Users/user/Desktop",
    "executable": false
  }
]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!
Do you have an explanation (or a link to one) for why the square brackets are needed? And do you have any idea why the other variant might be working in one instance and not the other?

Comment: square brackets are not strictly necessary. With you script, I get same result on my machine. I'm using `$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.4.12(1)-release`